# ASP.NET Core multiple authentication schemes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication

I want to implement 2 authentication schemes, but I have an error on my code which says:

> The expression assigned to AuthSchemes must be constants

Code:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AuthSchemes )]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SomeController : ControllerBase
{
        private const string AuthSchemes =
        IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme + "," +
        JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```

but it's ok if I do it this way:

```
private const string AuthSchemes =
        "Identity.Application" + "," +
        JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```

How can I fix the first implementation?

Comment: Here is the definition of IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme: `public static readonly string ApplicationScheme;` - so despite the classname, it's not actually a const! JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme however, is defined as a const.